# What am I doing wrong when converting jQuery code to axios

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, axios

I have code that uses jQuery to submit a PUT request in JSON String to a PGHP backend. I want to do this same thing in Axios. I have tried to use Axios as listed in code, and I get nothing back from server.

```js
let signupInfo = {};
signupInfo.account = {};
signupInfo.account = {};
signupInfo.account.type = 'affiliate';
signupInfo.user = {};
signupInfo.user.userName = 'some_name';
signupInfo.site = {};
signupInfo.siteId = 'aqterm';
signupInfo.request = 'availability';
signupInfo.type = 'affiliate';
signupInfo.mode = 'affiliate';

let packagedSignUpInfoData = base64encode(JSON.stringify(signupInfo));

const thePackageObject = {
  "params": {
    "data": packagedSignUpInfoData
  }
};

let packagedData = JSON.stringify(thePackageObject);
let url_request = "https://somedomain.com/aqmprocess";

$.ajax({
  url: "https://somedomain.com/aqmprocess",
  type: 'put',
  data: packagedData,
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  error: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.successful === true) {
      console.log(response);
    } else if (response.successful === false) { // we have a form error
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the axios version:

```
const options = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: packagedData,
  "https://somedomain.com/aqmprocess",
};

let promise = axios(options).then(function(response) {
  if (response.success === true) {
    return response.data.token;
  }
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The results would be returning back an object

```
{ "successful": true, "message": "available" }
```

Comment: Maybe inside promise `response.data.successful` instead of `response.data.success` ?

Comment: Remove method: ‘PUT’ from options object and specify the method to the axios.  Like axios.put